Can I print and sell 3D models licensed under CC BY-SA?
Can I print and sell 3D models licensed under CC BY-SA? I am selling something that has a CC-BY-SA license.

Yes.  Just make sure you also comply with all of the terms of the license: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en

@GregMiller - you should post that as an answer

Hi Chee and welcome. If you feel that your question isn't a duplicate of the linked question please [edit] and explain why not. That will trigger a reopen vote.

Why is this closed as duplicate of literally the opposite?

@SF. - If you feel that it should be reopened then please flag it as such (or vote to reopen). I closed it as the answers to the other question seemed to address the NC - (and therefore) the C aspect of this question. I could be incorrect though :-)

@SF and Chee - It appears that I incorrectly closed the question as a duplicate, and that Trish's answer doesn't adequately cover the commercial aspect of this question. I've reopened it. Apologies to all.

Yes, you can - but the license requires you provide the correct attribution and distribute your prints under the same license - and that does specifically include allowing creation of derivative works and remixes.
Probably the best approach would be to provide a label that identifies you (the author of the derivative), the original author of the model, and a link to the 3D model (your version if you modify the original project; author's if you print as-is) alongside with Creative Commons license tag and link to the license.

(or whichever version of CC the author uses; you can't "upgrade to newest" willy-nilly under the share-alike rules).
Make the label also available alongside any sales listing (a photo of the print is still a derivative work of it!). While providing a link to the original 3D model could be argued not to be mandatory, it will be keeping up with the spirit of the license instead of trying to bend the rules. Such link will allow your customers for easier remixing than 'break your physical print and kit-bash it with other pieces of plastic' which going by the license "as written" would be the only way they can utilize their right to remix.
